# Catalog Price Rules Contains Condition

Tags: magento-1.9, price, catalog-price-rules, rules

I need to make discount oin several product wich skus contain "1513437" like
sku1 = 1513437_01
sku2 = 1513437_02
etc...
So i set a new rule setting condition as

> sku contains 1513437

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

Magento version 1.9.2.2

with flat mode off it works.

with flat mode on it does not work.

If I use "contain" condition those product are not affected.

If I use "does not contain" condition those product are affected.

If I use "contain" condition whit perfect match it works.

So I think the problem is that the sql query use LIKE instead %LIKE% when flat mode is on

Comment: Your comment : Of course the Catalog Price Rule has been applied, but it didn't work. I tried diabling product_flat and category_flat than it work. But enabling product_flat and category_flat it didn't work again

Comment: have your setup cron jop on your server?

Comment: cron job is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is in the `getOperatorCondition()` in app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Resource/Rule/Condition/SqlBuilder.php

```
            case '!{}':
            if (preg_match('/^.*(category_id)$/', $field) && is_array($value)) {
                $selectOperator = ' IN (?)';
            } else {
                $selectOperator = ' LIKE ?';
            }
            if (substr($operator, 0, 1) == '!') {
                $selectOperator = ' NOT' . $selectOperator;
            }
            break;
```

on line 67

To solve this problem you can hack the file core changing LIKE with %LIKE% or just simply add % in condition like:

> sku contains %1513437%

Answer (score 1):

Is **Catalog Price Rule** has been applied, to do so please open price rule and press **Save and Apply** button. Its work for me see below screen shot.
[image]
[image]

---

I figure out this problem and regenerated in my magento shop. I tried below steps which is worked for me.

> Step 1: Make you **Catalog Price Rule** status to **Inactive** and
>   perform **Save and Apply** action.
>
> Step 2: Disabled **Flat Catalog Category** & **Flat Catalog Product**
>   option in *System > Configuration > CATALOG > Catalog > Frontend*
>
> Step 3: Now change the status of your catalog price rule to **Active**
>   and clicked on **Save and Apply** button.
>
> Step 4: Now enabled **Flat Catalog Category** & **Flat Catalog
>   Product** and cleared cache and re-indexed **Product Flat Data** &
>   **Category Flat Data**

Hope this trick work for you!

Comment: Of course the Catalog Price Rule has been applied, but it didn't work.
I tried diabling product_flat and category_flat than it work.
But enabling product_flat and category_flat it didn't work again

Comment: I added trick in answer which might be fix your problem.

Comment: already tryed. Nex time rules ar applied the doesn't work again.

Comment: I didn't get "_Nex time rules ar applied the doesn't work again._" ?

Comment: Catalog rules are update by cron job

Answer (score 1):

I have improved the code provided by krybbio because it was not working properly for me.

In my case I have made the following replacements:

First line 96 I have replace:

```
foreach ($value as $v) {
    $results[] = $this->_adapter->quoteInto("{$field}{$selectOperator}", $v);
}
```

With:

```
foreach ($value as $v) {
    if (in_array($operator, array("{}", "!{}"))) {
        $v = "%".$v."%";
    }
    $results[] = $this->_adapter->quoteInto("{$field}{$selectOperator}", $v);
}
```

Then line 114 I have replaced:

```
} else {
    $result = $this->_adapter->quoteInto("{$field}{$selectOperator}", $value);
}
```

With:

```
} else {
    if (in_array($operator, array("{}", "!{}"))) {
        $value = "%".$value."%";
    }
    $result = $this->_adapter->quoteInto("{$field}{$selectOperator}", $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1/ Disabled the flat mode -> Create catalog price rules -> save & apply the rules -> check on front-end to be sure the rule is applied

2/ Enabled flat mode -> check on front-end and check the tables "catalogrule_product" and "catalogrule_product_price" then feedback if somethings is still wrong

Hope this help

Comment: This works but next time rules are appied the issue is back.
This issue is valid for some condition not all.
In this particular case condirtion "contains" doesn't work if flat mode is enable.

Comment: @krybbio: have you clicked on "save & apply the rules" ? When you click on it, the final promotion price will be calculated. No matter what to use flat mode or not, the promotion price is stored in its own table.

Comment: i clicked "save & apply the rules" but it works only if flat mode is off.