# What is the difference between magento 1.9.2.4 and magento 1.9.3.0?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.4, ce-1.9.3.0

Magento has released it's new community edition version `1.9.3.0`.

I am very curious to know **what are the differences with previous Magento edition?**

I want to know full details about the what is the difference with its feature in `Magento 1.9.3.0`.

and also want to know what step needs to take after upgrade my current site to `1.9.3.0` which is in `Magento 1.9.2.4`?

Comment: Another bug in 1.9.3.0 I mention in http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142087/mixing-up-of-option-labels-of-multiselect-attributes-after-saving/142156#142156. You may add this to your list

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can find the full list of differences in the official release notes: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1930

### Module fixing all the bugs

This module fixes the known bugs I'm trying to keep it up to date: https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes

### Side note

There used to be **a bug in Magento where the passwords would not display in the new account email template.** Most of the people (including me) assumed it was a security enhancement (see here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/46793/2380) but it was actually a bug which has been fixed in 1.9.3.0.

### Known issues

As of now, there's several known bugs with 1.9.3.0:

- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : [Magento 1.9.3: every product is displayed in the search in full text mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/140707/2380) (fixed in module above)
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : [SOAP connection problems after 1.9.3.0 update](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/140761/2380) (fixed in module above)
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : Send auto generated password does not work for some customers, fix here: https://gist.github.com/p3mbo/224f01996ff5b4849d189c38325c0bbd (fixed in module above)
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : Possible issue with bundle price as configured: [Upgraded from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3 Bundle "Price as configured" Price Shows Zero](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141042/2380) (fixed in module above)
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : Dropdown attributes frontend label disappears under certain conditions: https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes/pull/1 (fixed in module above)
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : Undefined index session_expire_timestamp: https://tomlankhorst.nl/fix-magento-undefined-index-session_expire_timestamp/ (fixed in module above)
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : [Free shipping using sales rules now calculated from subtotal excluding tax](https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes/issues/4), fix here: https://gist.github.com/andrew-smart/c7db5b04b24e77dd344919ce64ecf2f1 (fixed in module above)
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : [Flow Password Cron Task does not work](https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes/issues/6) (fixed in module above)
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : [Every page redirect to homepage when session cookie lifetime is set to 0](https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes/pull/7) (fixed in module above)
- Backward incompatible change for modules using the old uploader block (also affects 8788): https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142013/2380
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : [Exception `addCrumbs()` method call (in case `getStoreConfig(web/default/show_cms_breadcrumbs)` ) is undefined](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140803/2380)
- Possible issues with configurable swatches and product tabs: [Magento 1.9.3 upgrade other problems encountered](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141010/2380) and [Configurable Swatches not working after 1.9.3 Upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/142404/2380)
- Image uploader not working anymore: [Image uploader not working after Magento 1.9.3 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/142636/2380) / [After Upgrading to 1.9.3 I can't insert a product image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/142838/2380)
- Images missing from the backend but present on front end: [Image problem in the Admin after 1.9.3 upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/143216/2380) / [After upgrading to 1.9.3 - none of my product images are showing in the backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/142911/2380)
- **Fixed in 1.9.3.1** : Cannot upload more than 7 images via CSV import: [When import Configurable product csv only 7 image upload in magento1.9.2.3?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/143231/2380)
- Default serialized configuration values do not work anymore: [Default configuration value for serialized_array settings is ignored](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/146978/2380)
- Not a 1.9.3 bug actually (see here: [Catalog Price Rules Contains Condition](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97299/catalog-price-rules-contains-condition)) <del>With flat catalog enabled, **catalog rule condition such as "sku" contains "foo" don't work anymore**</del>

Also please note that the JS that handles the product options price has been moved from `/js/varien/product.js` to `/js/varien/product_options.js` so don't forget to add that file to your theme if you're facing the following issue: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141375/2380

### PHP 7

For those using PHP 7 and the Inchoo module, Inchoo has released a new version of the module (2.0.0) which is only compatible with 1.9.3 don't forget to update: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Comment: If we are developing an extension so what are the new steps or what is change for coding point of view

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala see my edit

Comment: There is also a big bug with the SOAP API, see here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/140761/4087

Comment: @BlueC thanks I forgot to update my post indeed

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism another one, not a bug as such but will break themes, is that for some reason the Product.OptionsPrice javascript class has been moved from /js/varien/product.js to a new file called /js/varien/product_options.js - this new file will need to be included via the theme layout xml

Comment: also include this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142087/mixing-up-of-option-labels-of-multiselect-attributes-after-saving/142156#142156 error in your answer, it may help others

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala it's already there: "Dropdown attributes frontend label disappears under certain conditions: https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes/pull/1 "

Answer (score 4):

There are two backward-incompatible changes in Magento 1.9.3:

1. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Wysiwyg_Images_Content_Uploader` parent class is removed.
2. `Mage_Uploader_Model_Config_Abstract` overrides the magic method `__call` and its behavior can be inconsistent.

Please check if any extensions/customisations are using/extending these functions/classes.

Also make sure after upgrading to Magento 1.9.3 to remove the following files to avoid security issues:

1. skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
2. skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
3. skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf

For more information, refer to the [release notes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1930).

Answer (score 2):

I am not a big fan of patching. Personally I remove all Magento files from their directories then upload the new version (using a shell script). All the files installed over the years like modules or themes are still there. For database I make a comparison between fresh installed versions. One way is creating or removing the columns/tables into the database, the other way is installing again Magento just changing /app/etc/local.xml file name. I prefer the first one.

If you do not change the database structure to version 1.9.3.0 you will get some errors or you cannot load admin area. If anyone is interested in some comparisons for Magento directories and databases between Magento CE 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.0 just download the file from here:

[Magento Comparison: versions 1.9.2.4 - 1.9.3.0](https://we.tl/TxAKMTsapX)

There are two html files with very nice visual results.

I updated 4 stores today using my method instead of patching. All are running without any issues.

Comment: I agree about not patching, and also agree that upgrading in-place is troublesome because it leaves old files that should no longer be present, so I think your method of removing all Magento files then adding the new version is a good approach. However, your database work seems un-neccessary to me, why not just use "n98-magerun sys:setup:incremental" to run the setup scripts and update the database automatically to the new version?

Comment: I appreciate for your suggestion. I agree n98-magerun is a very powerful tool but I prefer controling by myself the whole update process. As I mentioned before doing all that stuff I try understanding what is new with every version. After updating a test version I proceed to production. The stores I manage want no trouble and pay for avoiding them. Removing all previous Magento files and keeping an eye on the database is the best method for updating to new versions. I am doing this method since 1.7.0.2 and never encountered an issue. Patching leaves residues in file system and database

Comment: I understand, and I think its a good method. May I ask what tool you use to compare the databases and create an update script from that comparison?

Comment: I am using Araxis Merge for comparing folders and files. It gives me nice reports and it can create an update script. But I prefer analyzing the whole information from comparison even it takes 1 -  2 days. I create by myself the update script which consists of deleting the file system from previous Magento version and copying the new version. For database it is a script too after removing all common parts. When you have over 30 stores to update it is negligible  spending 1 - 2 days understanding the update process you will do. That's why I never used a patch for more than 4 years.

Comment: can you share the file Magento Comparison with some hosting that will last more than couple days? thanks

Comment: @sellio: I will post these days a new link for downloading a file which contains a comparison in file contents and file system trees between  1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.1. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in finding out what are the changes between Magento CE 1.9.2.4 and 1.9.3.1 download the following archives:

- **Folder Comparison Report**:
  http://www.megafileupload.com/89dx/FolderComparisonReport.zip
- **Database Comparison Report**:
  http://www.megafileupload.com/89dm/DatabaseComparisonReport.zip

There are two html files with very nice visual results.

Answer (score 0):

- Restored the old tax calculation algorithm for shipping charges.
  The patch to apply new calculation will be available on request.
- Resolved an issue with setting the session lifetime to 0.
- The monthly cron job that cleans up the table that contains IP
  addresses and passwords runs properly.
- All configurable product images are imported.
- You no longer get an exception due to an undefined addCrumbs() method
  call. Resolved the error **Notice**: `Undefined index:session_expire_timestamp` when accessing the storefront.
- Values for drop-down label values are saved correctly.
- The "Price as configured" for bundle products displays correctly in
  the shopping cart.
- Auto-generated passwords are sent to new customers as expected.
- The method
  `Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract::processingMethodResult()`
  accepts scalar and array values.
- The default MySQL Full-Text search works as expected; it no longer
  returns all products.
- Prevented a potential [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
  vulnerability by changing the form key when a customer signs out of
  the storefront.
- Catalog price rules return the correct price.
- Indexers now update all products instead of skipping the last product
  updated.