# Magento 1.9.3 upgrade other problems encountered

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

After **1.9.3.0** version upgrade, the only problems faced so far are

1. Configurable Swatches stopped working (on all themes)
2. Product tabs content are all shown in product page (specific themes)

Has anyone else encountered these problems? Possible solutions?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: For configurable swatches, are you using a custom theme? Or a customised RWD/default theme?

Comment: @jehzlau I am currently using a theme from Ubertheme. But configurable swatches do not work on any "native" magento theme after the version upgrade.FYI I build and run the store on a self learn basis.

Comment: any error messages (eg in your browser's JS console)?

Comment: 1) TypeError: Product.OptionsPrice is not a constructor
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice({"priceFormat":{"pattern":"%s\u00a0\...  - 

2)TypeError: $(...) is null 
$('bug_tracking_link').target = "varien_external"; -

3)TypeError: optionsPrice is undefined
var productId = optionsPrice.productId; //get product ID from options price obje...

Got these errors from firebug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying the fix described at
[Product.OptionsPrice is not a constructor magento 1.9.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141374/product-optionsprice-is-not-a-constructor-magento-1-9-3/141375#141375)
product tabs and configurable swatches are fixed!
I use the Trex theme from Ubertheme