# Product.OptionsPrice is not a constructor magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, product, javascript, upgrade, ce-1.9.3.0

I have upgrade magento `1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.`

I am facing the following error in the console in product page.

```
TypeError: Product.OptionsPrice is not a constructor

var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice([]);
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It's caused by your custom theme not adding the new `product_options.js` file.

Edit your theme layout file (either `local.xml` or `catalog.xml`) and add the following under the `<catalog_product_view>` handle (or whatever page handle you're having the problem on):

```
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
```

Comment: To fix this issue on category listing page also add the js under `catalog_category_default` handle

Comment: This JS is added in the 3 page layout handles, so make sure to add it under all these  layout handles  catalog_product_view , catalog_product_send , catalog_product_compare_index in catalog.xml inside your theme layout folder if this JS is found missing

Comment: Same issue i had faced when i upgrade Magento version 1.8.1 to 1.9.3.7

Comment: @Raphael at Digital Pianism why you don't use `<reference name="head">`?