# Uncaught TypeError: is not a conscructor after update to 1.9.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento1.9.3

After updating from Magento 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 on my dev site the tabs on my item page broke. I looked in console for the dev site and see this error-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Product.optionsPrice is not a constructor
at http://www.example.com/circuit-breaker-1-pole-c-curve-2-amp-ul1077:573:24(anonymous function) @ circuit-breaker-1-pole-c-curve-2-amp-ul1077:573
```

That code is-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var optionsPrice = new Product.optionsPrice([]);
if( jQuery ){
    jQuery( "#ja-tab-products" ).ready( function($) {
        $( "#ja-tab-products" ).jaContentTabs();                              
    } );
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        urllocation =  window.location;

        if(urllocation.toString().indexOf("#review-form") > 0){
           jQuery("ul.ja-tab-navigator").find("a[href='#ja-tabitem-reviewform']").trigger("click");
           window.location = "#ja-tabitem-reviews";
        }
});
```

The line of code that is throwing the error is-

```
var optionsPrice = new Product.optionsPrice([]);
```

The production site on 1.9.2 with the exact same code works fine. Why am I getting an error? How do I get the tabs functioning again?

Comment: Just found this- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141374/product-optionsprice-is-not-a-constructor-magento-1-9-3 Problem solved