# Upgraded from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3 Bundle "Price as configured" Price Shows Zero

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, bundled-product, ce-1.9.3.0

I just upgraded from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3 and having a problem with the Bundle "Price as configured" price. The problem is it always shows zero no matter which bundle sub-products are selected. It was completely fine in 1.9.2.4 and only started happening in 1.9.3. By the way, **this only happens to the price at the bottom near the "add to cart" button. The price at the top (right after the product title) updates as expected**. This is plain unmodified RWD theme. Please help.

[image]

Comment: I just installed a fresh version of 1.9.3 and it confirms that it's definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that issue, copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Type/Composite.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Type/Composite.php`

Then edit the `app/code/local` version of the file and line 130 replace:

```
'idSuffix'            => '',
```

With:

```
'idSuffix'            => '_clone',
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that if & when Magento updates their core file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Type/Composite.php` your system will miss it as it will be using  `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Type/Composite.php` .  For another approach check out http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141470/6549

Comment: @Holy well this is a temporary fix while Magento working on the new version, not meant to stay on the server

Answer (score 0):

There is also a module available which fixes this issue with a class rewrite:
https://github.com/rossmc/JsonPriceFix

I also have a different solution at:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141470/6549

But I think the module is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Magento 1.9.3 has a lot of bugs I suggest you check that out: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140826/2380

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, thanks, very useful