# Issue on editing "Manage Label / Options" on version 1.14.3.0

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, magento-enterprise, backend, ee-1.14.3.0

Is there any body having issues when editing attributes labels in a multi store installation?

I believe that  method call `array_fill` in: `\Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController::_filterPostData`
is messing around with array keys and as consequence the translations get swapped after saving.

Checking [release notes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ee1.14_release-notes.html#ee114-11430) I can see in **Other Fixes**:

> The configuration setting **Allow HTML Tags on Frontend** is honored.

This make me think that "honoring the setting" introduced this weird behavior.

Btw reverting the offending line to previous version fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a known issue, see the [list of know issues here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140826/2380)

The fix is available in the 1.9.3.0 bug fixes repository: https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes