# Configurable Swatches not working after 1.9.3 Upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, upgrade, product-images, swatches

After upgrading Magento from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3, configurable swatches appears to be broken on the product page for all themes. When you click on color swatches (other than the default) the product image no longer switches. The grid and list product view still work but I receive the following js error on all product pages:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'productId' of undefined**

Has anyone else experienced this issue and been able to resolve it?

Comment: we were not able to reproduce it

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon the previous answer, you are probably overriding catalog.xml in your theme and there was a change to catalog.xml in this update. They removed some functionality from varien/product.js and added it to a new file varien/product_options.js. Check the rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml and you will see they've added a line. To fix, edit the catalog.xml file in your theme to include varien/product_options.js as show below.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong because I need more information, check your file

> varien/product_options.js

it must be included after this file

> varien/product.js