# Image uploader not working after Magento 1.9.3 upgrade

Tags: product-images, image-upload, magento1.9.3

Product image uploader not work after Magento 1.9.3 upgrade.

I click browse and then upload, it says complete for a second or 2 and then disappears and then no image displays.

What the issue?

Comment: Can you please post error log

Answer (score 6):

The Flash uploader has been replaced with a JS one. You only need to make sure you haven't missed the /js folder in the upgrade, and add this to your layout file

Layout file url :/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/aijko/widgetimagechooser.xml

```
    <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</file></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: And remove this if you have it anywhere in your layouts:

Comment: `<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/flex.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/FABridge.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/browser.js</script></action>
       </reference>`

Answer (score 3):

Have you uploaded any patches to your site ?

if yes then which patch ?

if you upload, then you need to go `/lib/Varien/File` and open `Uploader.php`

Go to line number 219 and change the permission 640 to 644.

Example: `chmod($destinationFile, 0644);`

Answer (score 2):

**This solution worked for me!**
Remove this if you have it anywhere in your layouts:

```
<reference name="head"> <action method="addJs"><script>lib/flex.js</script></action> <action method="addJs"><script>lib/FABridge.js</script></action> <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js</scrip‌​t></action> <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/browser.js</script></a‌​ction> </reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

As part of the 1.9.3/SUPEE update the SWF files for the uploader have been removed. You can switch to using an HTML based uploader extension. This is the extension I have chosen to use for the time being:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/maven-html5-uploader.html

In general, Flash has too many vulnerabilities and is not supported on mobile. Having an HTML based uploader will let you admin from almost any device.

Comment: 1.9.3 already replaces the Flash uploader with HTML uploader. There is no need for additional extension.