# Saving label values in Attribute, moves label values to other website views

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, ce-1.9.3.0

When I try to save the labels within a attribute, it moves the values. From Storeview C to Storeview B.

I've added 2 images to make it more clear.

[image: This is how the values are filled in by me, and before clicking save]

1. This is how the values are filled in by me, and before clicking save

[image]

2. This is what happens after I hit save, some values disappeared.. and some are moved. Storeview A remains intact, but all other are moved to another position or deleted.

Does maybe anyone knows what can be the problem? And which core file in handling the saving of these attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in 1.9.3.0 as listed here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140826/2380 (number 5 in the list).

The fix is available in this module as well as other 1.9.3.0 bug fixes: https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes

Comment: @Bernd feel free to mark your question as solved so it'll benefit for others

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie, but I can't find the option to solve the question as answered.

Comment: @bernd the check mark below the upvote count on the left side of my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug of Magento 1.9.3 version.
We solved this way:

- we backed up the folder /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml renaming it to /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml_1.9.3
- we downloaded the older 1.9.2.4 Magento CE version from Magento official website
- we uploaded just the /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml folder.

Deleted cache, logout & login in admin, and everything is saving again.