# SoapFault exception: [1] Internal Error after upgrading to magento 1.9.3

Tags: soap, exception, magento1.9.3

After upgrading to Magento 1.9.3, I am having loads of problem, currently I am having the above error.

After looking at the exception log here is what I find:

> SoapFault exception: [1] Internal Error. Please see log for details.

in `/home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php:196`
Stack trace:

> 0
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(140):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap->fault('1', 'Internal Error....')
>
> 1
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(48):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->_fault('internal')
>
> 2
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(559):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->handlePhpError(4096, 'Argument
>   1 pass...', '/home1/mysitename...', 559, Array)
>
> 3
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(299):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->processingMethodResult('default')
>
> 4
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Wsi/Handler.php(78):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->call('20dc1668276687a...',
>   'linnLive.getSto...', Array)
>
> 5 [internal function]:
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_WSI_Handler->__call('linnLiveGetStor...', Array)
>
> 6 [internal function]:
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_WSI_Handler->linnLiveGetStoreCode(Object(stdClass))
>
> 7
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php(889):
>   SoapServer->handle('\xEF\xBB\xBF
>
> 8
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Wsi/Adapter/Soap.php(98):
>   Zend_Soap_Server->handle()
>
> 9
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server.php(138):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server_WSI_Adapter_Soap->run()
>
> 10
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Api/controllers/V2/SoapController.php(46):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Server->run()
>
> 11
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   Mage_Api_V2_SoapController->indexAction()
>
> 12
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
>
> 13
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> 14
>   /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> 15 /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/app/Mage.php(684):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> 16 /home1/mysitename/public_html/mysitefolder/index.php(83):
>   Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> 17 {main}

Below is soap.php

```
class Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap
extends Varien_Object
implements Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Interface
```

{
    /**
     * Wsdl config
     *
     * @var Varien_Object
     */
    protected $wsdlConfig = null;

```
/**
 * Soap server
 *
 * @var SoapServer
 */
protected $_soap = null;

/**
 * Internal constructor
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->wsdlConfig = $this->_getWsdlConfig();
}

/**
 * Get wsdl config
 *
 * @return Varien_Object
 */
protected function _getWsdlConfig()
{
    $wsdlConfig = new Varien_Object();
    $queryParams = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getQuery();
    if (isset($queryParams['wsdl'])) {
        unset($queryParams['wsdl']);
    }

    $wsdlConfig->setUrl(htmlspecialchars(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_query'=>$queryParams))));
    $wsdlConfig->setName('Magento');
    $wsdlConfig->setHandler($this->getHandler());
    return $wsdlConfig;
}

/**
 * Set handler class name for webservice
 *
 * @param string $handler
 * @return Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap
 */
public function setHandler($handler)
{
    $this->setData('handler', $handler);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrive handler class name for webservice
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getHandler()
{
    return $this->getData('handler');
}

/**
 * Set webservice api controller
 *
 * @param Mage_Api_Controller_Action $controller
 * @return Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap
 */
public function setController(Mage_Api_Controller_Action $controller)
{
     $this->setData('controller', $controller);
     return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrive webservice api controller. If no controller have been set - emulate it by the use of Varien_Object
 *
 * @return Mage_Api_Controller_Action|Varien_Object
 */
public function getController()
{
    $controller = $this->getData('controller');

    if (null === $controller) {
        $controller = new Varien_Object(
            array('request' => Mage::app()->getRequest(), 'response' => Mage::app()->getResponse())
        );

        $this->setData('controller', $controller);
    }
    return $controller;
}

/**
 * Run webservice
 *
 * @param Mage_Api_Controller_Action $controller
 * @return Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap
 */
public function run()
{
    $apiConfigCharset = Mage::getStoreConfig("api/config/charset");

    if ($this->getController()->getRequest()->getParam('wsdl') !== null) {
        // Generating wsdl content from template
        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
        $io->open(array('path'=>Mage::getModuleDir('etc', 'Mage_Api')));

        $wsdlContent = $io->read('wsdl.xml');

        $template = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');

        $template->setVariables(array('wsdl' => $this->wsdlConfig));

        $this->getController()->getResponse()
            ->clearHeaders()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset='.$apiConfigCharset)
            ->setBody(
                preg_replace(
                    '/<\?xml version="([^\"]+)"([^\>]+)>/i',
                    '<?xml version="$1" encoding="'.$apiConfigCharset.'"?>',
                    $template->filter($wsdlContent)
                )
            );
    } else {
        try {
            $this->_instantiateServer();

            $this->getController()->getResponse()
                ->clearHeaders()
                ->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset='.$apiConfigCharset)
                ->setBody(
                        preg_replace(
                            '/<\?xml version="([^\"]+)"([^\>]+)>/i',
                            '<?xml version="$1" encoding="'.$apiConfigCharset.'"?>',
                            $this->_soap->handle()
                        )
                );
        } catch( Zend_Soap_Server_Exception $e ) {
            $this->fault( $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
        } catch( Exception $e ) {
            $this->fault( $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Dispatch webservice fault
 *
 * @param int $code
 * @param string $message
 */
public function fault($code, $message)
{
    if ($this->_extensionLoaded()) {
        throw new SoapFault($code, $message);
    } else {
        die('<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>' . $code . '</faultcode>
            <faultstring>' . $message . '</faultstring>
            </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');
    }

}

/**
 * Check whether Soap extension is loaded
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _extensionLoaded()
{
    return class_exists('SoapServer', false);
}

/**
 * Transform wsdl url if $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] is set
 *
 * @param array
 * @return String
 */
protected function getWsdlUrl($params = null, $withAuth = true)
{
    $urlModel = Mage::getModel('core/url')
        ->setUseSession(false);

    $wsdlUrl = $params !== null
        ? $urlModel->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true, '_query' => $params))
        : $urlModel->getUrl('*/*/*');

    if ( $withAuth ) {
        $phpAuthUser = rawurlencode($this->getController()->getRequest()->getServer('PHP_AUTH_USER', false));
        $phpAuthPw = rawurlencode($this->getController()->getRequest()->getServer('PHP_AUTH_PW', false));
        $scheme = rawurlencode($this->getController()->getRequest()->getScheme());

        if ($phpAuthUser && $phpAuthPw) {
            $wsdlUrl = sprintf("%s://%s:%s@%s", $scheme, $phpAuthUser, $phpAuthPw,
                str_replace($scheme . '://', '', $wsdlUrl));
        }
    }

    return $wsdlUrl;
}

/**
 * Try to instantiate Zend_Soap_Server
 * If schema import error is caught, it will retry in 1 second.
 *
 * @throws Zend_Soap_Server_Exception
 */
protected function _instantiateServer()
{
    $apiConfigCharset = Mage::getStoreConfig('api/config/charset');
    $wsdlCacheEnabled = (bool) Mage::getStoreConfig('api/config/wsdl_cache_enabled');

    if ($wsdlCacheEnabled) {
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '1');
    } else {
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');
    }

    $tries = 0;
    do {
        $retry = false;
        try {
            $this->_soap = new Zend_Soap_Server($this->getWsdlUrl(array("wsdl" => 1)),
                array('encoding' => $apiConfigCharset));
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            if (false !== strpos($e->getMessage(),
                "can't import schema from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'")
            ) {
                $retry = true;
                sleep(1);
            } else {
                throw $e;
            }
            $tries++;
        }
    } while ($retry && $tries < 5);
    use_soap_error_handler(false);
    $this->_soap
        ->setReturnResponse(true)
        ->setClass($this->getHandler());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

All the problem including this will be resolved if you following the following solution.

[Magento 1.9.3 All known problems](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140810/what-is-different-between-magento-1-9-2-4-and-magento-1-9-3-0/140826#140826)