# Subtotal for Free Shipping wrong since SUPEE-8788 patch

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, tax, free-shipping, supee-8788

I installed the SUPEE-8788 patch on our Magento installation (it was the latest version before that.)

However since the installation a weird bug pops up, which wasn't there before.

We have some Shopping Cart Price Rules, granting people Free Shipping from a certain subtotal (subtotal is TAX INCLUDED). This worked fine before as expected. Now the subtotal it uses in the calculation does NOT include the tax.

So let's have the example of Belgium, which has a 21% tax rate.

Conditions:
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

- Subtotal  equals or greater than  59,95
- Shipping Country  is  Belgium

Action:
Free Shipping

However, now since the update, the free shipping isn't granted at the expected 59.95 euros but at 72.54 euro (59.95 price (which actually already includes the tax) + 12.59 tax)

I tried to play around with the calculations settings at the configuration page but that doesn't seem to do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with 1.9.3.0 I'm not sure if it's because of SUPEE-8788 but I don't think so.

You can find details about it here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140826/2380 (see item # 7 in the list).