# Upgrade Magento from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.0

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, image, image-upload, chrome-browser

I upgraded My Magento from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.0 and I have no images in the admin panel.

First, browse file button and upload button was disappeared after I copied Media from Magento they came back but doesn't work I don't know how can I solve my problem.

I would be appreciated if help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? No image in admin? Do you mean no product images displayed in front?

Answer (score 0):

please check below files if it is there then delete it manually

```
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

I think this could be only possible error for your problem.

you can read this thing in below url to

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1930security-upgrade

**and also you can my question for more detail.**

[What is the difference between magento 1.9.2.4 and magento 1.9.3.0?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140810/what-is-the-difference-between-magento-1-9-2-4-and-magento-1-9-3-0)